# Word VBA Selection.TypeText and Selection.InsertParagraph inserting text in the wrong order

Tags: vba, excel, loops, ms-word, selection

I am trying to print certain columns from an Excel file with the `Selection.TypeText` function.
Unfortunately, the following code first prints all the results, and after that all the paragraphs.  I want the result:

```
result (tab) result (tab) result (tab) result (tab) result (paragraph)
```

The order of the results is correct, but the macro jumps to the end of the data to insert a paragraph, and then "jumps back" to fill in more data.

`noInt` and `noData` are two variables that are filled beforehand and are working.

```
For i = 2 To noInt
    For k = 2 To noData
        If exWb.Sheets("Table1").Cells(k, 1) = exWb.Sheets("Table2").Cells(i, 1) Then
            For j = 5 to 9
                Selection.TypeText exWb.Sheets("Table1").Cells(k, j) & vbTab
            Next j
       Selection.InsertParagraph
       End If
    Next k
Next i
```

Comment: the way that your code is set up, it would be: `result (tab) (paragraph) result (tab) (paragraph) ...` To get the formatting the way you would like, you have to put the `Selection.InsertParagraph` line just below the `Next j` line

Comment: Changed that. It still first prints all results and then all paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Selection`, use a `Range`.  Then you can reliably append text using `Range.InsertAfter`.  The below examples are in Word VBA; I can't put them in your Excel context since I don't have all the details.

#### MCVE of your code (not working)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

' A function just to display i, k, and j in a comprehensible manner
Public Function ijk(i As Long, j As Long, k As Long)
    ijk = "[I: " & CStr(i) & "; K: " & CStr(k) & "; J: " & CStr(j) & "]"
End Function

Public Sub NotWorking()
    Dim noInt As Long
    noInt = 3

    Dim noData As Long
    noData = 4

    Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long

    For i = 2 To noInt
        For k = 2 To noData
            For j = 5 To 9
                Selection.TypeText ijk(i, j, k) & vbTab
            Next j
            Selection.InsertParagraph
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

#### A working version

Replace Sub `NotWorking` above with this:

```
Public Sub Working()
    Dim noInt As Long
    noInt = 3

    Dim noData As Long
    noData = 4

    Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long

    ' *** Create a Range to refer to wherever the Selection is now
    Dim rDest As Range
    Set rDest = Selection.Range.Duplicate

    For i = 2 To noInt
        For k = 2 To noData
            For j = 5 To 9
                rDest.InsertAfter ijk(i, j, k) & vbTab    ' ***
            Next j
            rDest.InsertAfter Chr(13)                     ' ***
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

`Chr(13)` is a paragraph marker, so inserting it creates a new paragraph.

**Results**:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a possibility to insert something after a certain Placeholder String with range? And could I also for example insert a Table with the data after this placeholder string?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RiekRudolph You're welcome!  Those are good questions, but they are separate questions.  If this answer helped you, would you please upvote or accept as you see fit?  (See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).)  Then try to do what you are asking, and if you have trouble, ask a new question linking to this one and showing the code that's not working (just like you did here).  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: You could also use the `VbNewLine` constant instead of `Chr(13)`. Another thought: If the text is being inserted at a specific place in the document, you could add a bookmark there, and then use the `Bookmark("bookmark_name").Range` property.